# How can I change constraints per iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I'm using Xcode 7 currently and am trying to make small position updates, using auto layout, for iPhone 6 and 6+. The problem is there is no class or selection for these two, only "iphones in portrait" etc. How can I change a constraint for just these two iPhones in storyboard preferably? Is there a better way to do this? Can I have percent spacing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot do that IN storyboard, hook your `constraint` to a variable and check which is which then make your necessary adjustments.

Comment: I suggest to look into the UITraitCollectionEnvironment which is available from iOS 8 and above. This has three properties 1. UIInterfaceIdiom 2. SizeClass (e.g. Compact or Regular) and 3. Force touch. As per your question can get the device type and vertical or horizontal size. In the traitdidchange delegate method you can handle the necessary changes you need.